# Bash IP from file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, ip

I am trying to get the IPv4 addresses from a text file using the following command:

`grep -E -o '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9]))' file.txt`.

This will display the valid IP addresses but will also display the valid part from a longer invalid IP which I don't want.

Input example:

```
IP address one is 192.168.1.1, ip 2 is 192.168.1.2.
192.168.1.3  192.168.1.10.1
Output I get:
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.10
Output I want:
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

Comment: How is `file.txt`? A single address for each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude all matches where a `<digit>.` is present immediately before and a `.<digit>` immediately after the IP.

That is why you need a GNU `grep` with the following regex:

```
grep -Po '\b(?<!\d\.)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b(?!\.\d)' file
```

The `\b(?<!\d\.)` at the start matches a word boundary first (it means there must be no letter, digit or `_` immediately to the left of the current location) and there must be no digit and `.` sequence there, either.

The `\b(?!\.\d)` at the end matches a word boundary first (here, it means there must be no letter, digit or `_` immediately to the right of the current location) and there must be no `.` + digit sequence there, either.

See an [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/Y5kyIz):

```
s="IP address one is 192.168.1.1, ip 2 is 192.168.1.2.
192.168.1.3  192.168.1.10.1"
grep -Po '\b(?<!\d\.)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b(?!\.\d)' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

See the [PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/piGIqk/1).